# Does the Debian or Ubuntu Team support nvidia drivers with security updates after nvidias official support ends

Tags: nvidia, support

For example the nvidia-390 driver (the last one supporting fermi gpu's) is no longer supported by nvidia since [end of 2022](https://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3142/%7E/support-timeframes-for-unix-legacy-gpu-releases).

So in particular nvidia will not deliver any security updates anymore.

Does the Debian/Ubuntu maintainer of the package patch security updates by their own? If so, how long will the nvidia-390 driver be supported this way?

Comment: Package support can be seen by what repository its found in ... 'main' for example comes with 5 years of support; with extra provided via use of *Pro* or *ESM*, 'universe' in contrast ... etc.. Support varies on a *release* and *package* basis... so pick a specific package & look at where it is located.

Comment: Since this is a Ubuntu only site no one here can say for sure what Debian might do,